# Mathematica notebook opening off the screen

Tags: front-end, notebooks, dialog-window

I have an issue with opening *Mathematica* notebook. I'm using Student version of Mathematica 12.0 on Windows 10. When I initiate the Mathematica or create a new document from the start page, it opens without any problems. But when I click to open the already existing notebook, it seems to be opening off the screen with only a little bit of it visible on the far right edge (attached screenshot). I can't move it at all. Have you ever encountered this problem?

[image]

Comment: While not a Wolfram Language solution, you can use the menu Window > Arrange Windows > (I like Stack)

Comment: "I can't move it at all." You can press Alt+Space to open the window's system menu. Then simply press the underlined character of the "Move" menu item. Then you can move it using the keyboard (and then the mouse). Or use Win+arrow keys.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, I have encountered this problem very often. For me, the reason is that I have 2 screens on my desktop pc and when I save a notebook which is on the second screen and open this notebook later, e.g. on my MacBook, then it happens that the notebook window has coordinates outside my Mac screen-area.

The solution is simple: Assuming `testme.nb` is your notebook (you need to include the path as well), then you can do:

```
nb = NotebookOpen["testme.nb"];
SetOptions[nb, WindowMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}]
```

and it should jump to the upper left corner of your screen.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows, it is simpler to right-click the Mathematica icon on the taskbar, select the notebook, which is still off-screen, then hit Win-LeftArrow (or similar combinations) which will dock the notebook on the left of the visible screen.